# Getting crash - Signed apk /bundle but normal debug apk working fine

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to generate a signed APK after testing the APK crashes.

In my application, I was using navigation argument type with customized object passing value with proguard option enabled

in proguard  -- I'm only trying to ignore
-ignorewarnings

Can anyone help me out with this one

My build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {

    compileSdkVersion build_versions.compile_sdk
    buildToolsVersion build_versions.build_tools

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId build_versions.applicationId
        minSdkVersion build_versions.min_sdk
        targetSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode build_versions.versionCode
        versionName build_versions.versionName

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = build_versions.java_version
        freeCompilerArgs += ["-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"]
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility build_versions.java_version
        targetCompatibility build_versions.java_version
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your app level `build.gradle` here?

Comment: dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
min_sdk = 23
compile_sdk = 30
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

Couldnt past over all build here

Comment: Can you please update this in your question? To make it more readable and paste the complete file in your question.

Comment: Can you check pls ..now i changed the question body

Comment: Build file still seems incomplete. I can not see dependencies section. Can you please update the complete file? Also do you need to use `minifyEnabled ` & `shrinkResources` ? if not then try removing that or just making them false and see if app works in release.

Comment: Okay i will try and let but if we set false mean proguard is disable?

Comment: Yes. It Means that code will not be `obfuscated`. So, all the classes remain in it's original form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230533/discussion-between-gopal-s-and-mayur-gajra).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using proguard enable is true

in Proguard file

```
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
```

public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep public class com.model.classname{ *; }